# Unable to publish the MS Teams application using Teams CLI

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I want to publish the teams application from the [`@microsoft/teamsapp-cli`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/teamsapp-cli). I can see `teamsApp/update` is working fine but `teamsApp/publishAppPackage` from the same provision lifecycle configuration is giving me the error. Unfortunately (even with `--verbose` and `--debug`), this is all I am getting on the console.

```
AppStudioPlugin.TeamsAppPublishFailed: Unable to publish Teams app with ID APP_GUID .Request path: POST /emea/api/publishing/f99fd0c1-6340-48ff-a99e-2f542c84b4f1/appdefinitions?teamstoolkit=true
```

Lifecycle hook

```yaml
publish:
  - uses: teamsApp/update
    with:
      # Relative path to this file. This is the path for built zip file.
      appPackagePath: ./appPackage/build/appPackage.${{TEAMSFX_ENV}}.zip
  - uses: teamsApp/publishAppPackage
    with:
      appPackagePath: ./appPackage/build/appPackage.${{TEAMSFX_ENV}}.zip
    writeToEnvironmentFile:
      publishedAppId: TEAMS_APP_PUBLISHED_APP_ID
```

But when I publish manually from the [https://dev.teams.microsoft.com/apps/${APP_ID}/overview](https://dev.teams.microsoft.com/apps/$%7BAPP_ID%7D/overview)

[image]

And I can confirm the application (v1.1.0) was submitted for approval, and is now approved.

[image]